# Opening the Camera App in Windows Phone (7 or 8)

Tags: windows-phone

Is there a way to launch the camera app programmatically, from my own app?  I know that you can use one of the tasks to launch it, allowing the user to take a single photo, but I want the user to be able to take multiple photos.  The user could then just hit the back button to go back into the app.  I could then track which ones were new by the date/time they were taken.

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey, you can use **CameraCaptureTask** class to launch the camera application. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask)

With this class you can take advantage of the camera, to take multiple pictures or something else. You need to manipulate the **Completed** event.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but CameraCaptureTask only lets me capture a single image at a time.  Apparently my only option is to create my own camera interface using CaptureDevice, and handle it manually.  This will give me more control anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There is great article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that guides you to the entire process of adding a camera to your app. It even allows you to take multiple images, rename them and saves them to the Camera Roll of your phone.

You could then use the DateTime class to add the date and time of the photo to the photo name (along with the name of your app), thus allowing you to better track the images taken.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up doing basically exactly that, but at the time was hoping to skip all the coding by letting the built-in camera app take the pictures.  That doesn't seem possible though.